# How can I send large data over cURL?

Tags: php, curl, migration

I am migrating data from one server to another and I am using curl to do so. I have been successful so far, but there are some large entities that are not migrating!

I have tried `serialize` but even that is not working, no error is shown! The php has all settings configured to maximum.

```
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  echo $result;
  curl_close($ch);
```

I used this with both:

```
$stringPost = serialize($postDataFinalArray);
  $postdata = 'string='.$stringPost;`
```

and

```
 $postdata = http_build_query($postDataFinalArray);
```

please help!

The array size is 400540, COUNT_RECURSIVE.

Comment: What is your post_max_size set to?

Comment: Its set to:  max_input_vars = 1000000
post_max_size = 8M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post size is exceeding your set `post_max_size` of 8MB. Try increasing this to something like 64MB (or higher, depending on the size of the posted data) using in `php.ini`:

```
post_max_size=64M
```

or in a script:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
```

Comment: Ok, I have done that (and It worked)! What else can I do so that it goes on without error!

Comment: "...goes on without error" . Wait, there are other errors? If this worked, the other thing you can do is upvote the answer I provided :)